# How to insert on top in JQ?

Tags: json, key, jq

This can let me insert a key/value pair to a json, but how do I insert the `"k0": 0` before the `"k1": 1`?

[image]

I would like the result to be:

```
    {
        "k0": 0,
        "k1": 1
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: In versions of the C implementation of jq from 1.4 onwards, the ordering of keys can be specified.  Currently, gojq insists on ordering them for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is creating an object with only k0-0 pair and adding the input to it like so:

```
{k0: 0} + .
```